# Convert PCM to AAC or MP4 file without MediaMuxer

Tags: android, audio, mp4, aac

I need to convert a PCM file to AAC or MP4 file. Until now, I did it with `MediaCodec` and `MediaMuxer`, But MediaMuxer is supported from Android 4.3. Is there a method to do the conversion without the use of `MediaMuxer`?

My code is this:

```
MediaMuxer mux = null;
try {
    File inputFile = new File(filePath + ".pcm");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    mux = new MediaMuxer(filePath + ".mp4", MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

    MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(COMPRESSED_AUDIO_FILE_MIME_TYPE,
            SAMPLING_RATE, 1);
    outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
    outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, COMPRESSED_AUDIO_FILE_BIT_RATE);

    MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(COMPRESSED_AUDIO_FILE_MIME_TYPE);
    codec.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    codec.start();

    ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo outBuffInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    boolean hasMoreData = true;
    double presentationTimeUs = 0;
    int audioTrackIdx = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int percentComplete;

    do {

        int inputBufIndex = 0;
        while (inputBufIndex != -1 && hasMoreData) {
            inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(CODEC_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);

            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer dstBuf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                dstBuf.clear();

                int bytesRead = fis.read(tempBuffer, 0, dstBuf.limit());
                if (bytesRead == -1) { // -1 implies EOS
                    hasMoreData = false;
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, (long) presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                } else {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    dstBuf.put(tempBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, bytesRead, (long) presentationTimeUs, 0);
                    presentationTimeUs = 1000000l * (totalBytesRead / 2) / SAMPLING_RATE;
                }
            }
        }

        // Drain audio
        int outputBufIndex = 0;
        while (outputBufIndex != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {

            outputBufIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(outBuffInfo, CODEC_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
            if (outputBufIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer encodedData = codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];
                encodedData.position(outBuffInfo.offset);
                encodedData.limit(outBuffInfo.offset + outBuffInfo.size);

                if ((outBuffInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0 && outBuffInfo.size != 0) {
                    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);
                } else {

                    mux.writeSampleData(audioTrackIdx, codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex], outBuffInfo);
                    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);
                }
            } else if (outputBufIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                outputFormat = codec.getOutputFormat();
                Log.v("AUDIO", "Output format changed - " + outputFormat);
                audioTrackIdx = mux.addTrack(outputFormat);
                mux.start();
            } else if (outputBufIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                Log.e("AUDIO", "Output buffers changed during encode!");
            } else if (outputBufIndex != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER){
                Log.e("AUDIO", "Unknown return code from dequeueOutputBuffer - " + outputBufIndex);
            }
        }
        percentComplete = (int) Math.round(((float) totalBytesRead / (float) inputFile.length()) * 100.0);
        Log.v("AUDIO", "Conversion % - " + percentComplete);
    } while (outBuffInfo.flags != MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

    fis.close();
    mux.stop();
    mux.release();
```

Comment: Closevoter: please note that answers recommending tools doesn't mean that a question is asking for tools and makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already pointed out, there's **no public system API compatible with older version of Android** for this kind of job.

Anyway, you can pursue a custom solution **using a native encoder** (like *FFMPEG*). I can suggested you the following: [**timsu/android-aac-enc**](https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc/)

## Android AAC Encoder project

> Extraction of Android Stagefright VO AAC encoder with a nice Java API.

This project offers an **easy Java API for the underlying JNI encoder**, and it should be ready to use since the **native library is already compiled for generic *ARM* architectures** (please note that I haven't tested it). The whole library is just *500kb* so it won't fatten your APK that much.

For a quick test, import in your project the following parts:

1. [Java bindings](https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc/tree/master/src/com/todoroo/aacenc) for the native AAC encorder
2. Pre-compiled [AAC encoder .so library](https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc/tree/master/libs/armeabi)
3. [Example](https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc/blob/master/src/com/todoroo/aacenc/Main.java) of usage (speech encoding)

You should be able to easily adapt the example to your code.